# Survey Questions vs Contact Info

Tags: custom-fields, profile, civisurvey

CiviSurvey has two types of information we could collect - 'Contact Info' and 'Questions'. Is there any difference between these two from an implementation perspective? Would it make any difference if I add a profile in Contact Info vs Questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are limitations in CiviCRM profiles mixing Contact and Activity fields (survey responses are stored as activities).  If your profiles work as you expect during testing, there won't be any hidden side effects, but having two profiles on a survey is meant to allow you to ask for both contact-specific and survey-specific information on a single survey.